# Installing new fan and light

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, remote-control

The old fan was wired so it had a switch on wall for fan and switch for light. So I have 2 white wires, 2 black wire and ground from ceiling. This light works with remote. So 2 switches not needed. The fan only has a white, black and ground. How do I wire this with this set up?????

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both the box in the ceiling and the box in the wall? Also, what make and model is your ceiling fan?

Comment: I succeeded in using one set of black and white. Got hung up due to a loose wire. Got it going. Oh and ground of course.